# Save one variables after shutdown app

Tags: java, android, view, save

I have a problem with save varible value.

(android)

I have activity who extends View, but i don't know how use save and read from txt file in activity which extends View, letter I try serialization and deserialization other class who I call from Main activity. but no run.
It was not allow me call method who serialized and deserialized.

I need save Higscore from app. and I need know value higscore if I restart app.

```
public class Game extends View  {
```

I need put this value give to game class. But i don't know how.

Thanks for any ideas.

---

Save

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref =  getContext().getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        int newHighScore;
        editor.putInt(getContext().getString((R.string.saved_high_score), newHighScore);
        editor.commit();
```

.getActivity() have a red. Compailer doesn't know this method.

Read

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref2 = getContext().getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       int  defaultValue = 0;
        int highScore = sharedPref.getInt(getContext().getString((R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue));
```

.getActivity() have a red. Compailer doesn't know this method too
and
getContext().getString((R.string.saved_high_score), defaultValue) is underground 
(getInt (string, int) in SharedPreferencies cannot be aplied to (String))

Comment: Android provides several options for you to save persistent application data. Check out https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I haven't OnCreate in my activity, because I have only Canvas and all Paint on it every 50ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work for you:

Save value:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref =
getContext().getSharedPreferences("preferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt("highscore", [here goes your highscore]);
editor.commit();
```

Read value:

```
getContext().getSharedPreferences("preferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int defaultValue = 0;
    long highScore = sharedPref.getInt("highscore", defaultValue);
```

Comment: I try use your code, but .getActivity and getString
Error:(933, 17) error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()
Error:(936, 23) error: cannot find symbol method getString(int)
Error:(939, 41) error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()
Error:(941, 44) error: cannot find symbol method getString(int)

Comment: I've stated that in the answer already. Instead of getActivity() use getContext() with getString(...) use getContext().getString(...)
You get these from the context which can also be activity. 
This is basic stuff, so you should start with some fundamentals.

Comment: getContext().getActivity()   no run. get activity is still red.

Comment: just use getContext().getPreferences(...)

Comment: getContext().getActivity() change into getContext()
that's all

Comment: SharedPreferences sharedPref =
                getContext().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
.getPreferences is red now.

Comment: ok, sorry, try this
getContext().getSharedPreferences("preferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: It's Okk now. But now is problem getInt and putInt. 
I wrote problem Up.

Comment: I edited my answer. You should really go back to basics.

Comment: Thanks. everything is okay now. 
Thanks for your patience

Comment: I have problem.. I see so Thise code save variable while app running, if i restart app variable is 0.

Comment: it would only reset to 0 if app has been uninstalled or user data has been deleted